# Where to copy and paste Google OAuth after authentication's code?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

After got authenticated with Google [GTM OAUTH 2](https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2), there is another HTML page with instruction of "Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there" with code inside textfield below it.

Where to put this code?

While I also notice it prints this error:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication 0x17236500: {code="some_code..."} || Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<7b0a2022 and_some_data 0a>, json={
    error = "invalid_client";
    "error_description" = Unauthorized;
}}
```

and the code itself always is always changed after authentication. It seems the code is per session.

Any advise everyone?

Comment: you place it in the section of your code that handles the initial exchange of authentication code for an access token and a refresh token.  Really though your application should be handling that the user should not need to copy that code for you.